# Unlock Root reports success but still cannot perform root user actions

Tags: root-access, superuser

Initially, I have tried to root my tablet(retail brand, not one of the mainstream ones) using SuperOneClick but it failed. Then I seeked UnlockRoot's help. Everything ran so smoothly. It reported success and it restared my tablet to complete the process.

The problem is that after restart, I cannot see the superuser app and of course I cannot perform root actions, such as creating a folder in / directory, or installing Google Apps.

How to overcome this? Any ideas appreciated.

Edit:
About tablet info

https://www.dropbox.com/s/de1kv0fhqpnlfm0/Screenshot_2014-01-12-20-50-38.png

Comment: Have you installed SuperSu? You may need to flash the zip for it through recovery but it is also on the play store. Here is the Play Store link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu&hl=en_GB and here is the XDA link containing the zip: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1538053 You just flash it like you would a rom! Try that and if it doesn't work you may not actually be rooted! Any issues let me know and I'll try and help!

Comment: We're trying to get rid of the `tablet` tag -- could you give us the manufacture and model name of the device so we can create a tag for it?  Rooting is often very device-specific as well, so it may be helpful.

Comment: @RossC, the reason I want to root the tablet is that it doesnt have Google Apps preinstalled. So I cant take through Play Store. Furthermore, my recovery doesn't support zip installations. If it was, I would have flash the Google Apps package(probably)

Comment: @MatthewRead, the company is called Crystal Audio. As it is targetted only to the Greek market, I couldnt find sufficient documentation online

Comment: Without knowing the exact make and model I just can't tell what you can do. Can you check settings > about device and let us know. There MAY be a custom recovery somewhere you can use to flash the Zip files and get this resolved.

Comment: Sure...here is a screenshot from the about screen: https://www.dropbox.com/s/de1kv0fhqpnlfm0/Screenshot_2014-01-12-20-50-38.png